# Python - reshape nested array

Tags: python

I am looking to reshape an array as follows:

Current array

```
a.shape = (1,4)

a[0][0].shape = (144,256)
```

I want the array to instead be shape

```
(1,4,144,256)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Provide `a` also

Comment: Hi Rahul, What extra information about 'a' would you like?

Comment: `a.shape = (1,4)` when I run this..it gives me an error called `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. So how does your `a` looks like